# Convertin Wav file to bit array and back ( streamaudio )

Tags: c#, audio, wav

I need to convert a wave that i created inside my app into a bit array and then back.
I have no clue how to start.

This is my clase where i create the sound file.

```
    private void forecast(string forecast)
    {

        MemoryStream streamAudio = new MemoryStream();
        System.Media.SoundPlayer m_SoundPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();

        SpeechSynthesizer speech = new SpeechSynthesizer();

        speech.SetOutputToWaveStream(streamAudio);
        speech.Speak(forecast);
        streamAudio.Position = 0;
        m_SoundPlayer.Stream = streamAudio;
        m_SoundPlayer.Play();

        // Set the synthesizer output to null to release the stream. 
        speech.SetOutputToNull();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've called `Speak`, the data is in the `MemoryStream`. You can get that to a byte array and do whatever you like:

```
speech.Speak(forecast);
byte[] speechBytes = streamAudio.ToArray();
```

`speechBytes` contains the data you're looking for.